# Generating mysql dump

Tags: mysql

When I dump a db from mysql, is there a way out by which I can remove the lines `ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=528 ...` , `LOCK TABLES "controller_actions" WRITE;` and `UNLOCK TABLES;` . Opening the db file and removing these lines would be extremely tedious as the database is such huge.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to remove the `ENGINE` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` options; as far as I can tell there's no way to remove just these options. If you want to remove the entire `CREATE TABLE` statement, use the `--no-create-info` option. To prevent the `LOCK TABLE` and `UNLOCK TABLE` commands, use `--skip-add-locks`.